# which domain do I setup DKIM on?

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, dkim, email

I'm trying to set up DKIN on for my organizations bulk mailing operation. Our bulk mailer is on one domain, test-news.org but all our mailings have user@test.org on the from line. I'm confused as to whether I need to setup DKIM on test.org or test-news.org?

Comment: Which domain is used in the envelope sender address? (Does it match the From header?)

Answer (score 1):

You can decide which and generally it's better to do for your sender domain as test.org. But it's possible for mailers domain as well. It can depend on which is technically possible.
The receiving part going to check sender reputation depending on which domain you choose. So your sender reputation management going to be different. Otherwise the DKIM signing going to work ok in both cases. Here for example explains a little bit the same thing http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21751322-What-are-SPF-and-DKIM-and-do-I-need-to-set-them-up-